# Cannot send requests to a NET 8 WebApi backend that is on jenkins ci/cd pipeline

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, docker, jenkins

I created an item on jenkins.

[image]

here is my execute shell configs

[image]

here is my dockerfile

```
﻿FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["NobetciBorsa_API.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "NobetciBorsa_API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "NobetciBorsa_API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "NobetciBorsa_API.csproj" --no-restore -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "NobetciBorsa_API.dll"]
```

and here is console output on jenkins item

```
Started by user nobetciborsa
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/NobetciBorsa
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential JenkinsToken
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/NobetciBorsa/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/IMPORTRADER/BackEnd.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/IMPORTRADER/BackEnd.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.39.2'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials JenkinsToken
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/IMPORTRADER/BackEnd.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 236715bcad04306fea703188b4ad0b40d8c2d1b1 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 236715bcad04306fea703188b4ad0b40d8c2d1b1 # timeout=10
Commit message: "new port"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 236715bcad04306fea703188b4ad0b40d8c2d1b1 # timeout=10
[NobetciBorsa] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins6376362888161306814.sh
+ docker build -t nobetciborsa/jenkinswithdockerlimitless .
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 564B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
#2 DONE 0.1s

#3 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
#3 DONE 0.1s

#4 [internal] load .dockerignore
#4 transferring context: 356B done
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0@sha256:8e77ad6fb7c33c17f026424d3bef05ea2ee15d1621e28f312adeab4dc1005866
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0@sha256:1d6ca86c35975c08bd63a066f190fb7bd68fbc2d675d70b2728d458921743a24
#6 DONE 0.0s

#7 [internal] load build context
#7 transferring context: 2.78kB done
#7 DONE 0.0s

#8 [build 5/7] COPY . .
#8 CACHED

#9 [publish 1/1] RUN dotnet publish "NobetciBorsa_API.csproj" --no-restore -c Release -o /app/publish
#9 CACHED

#10 [build 6/7] WORKDIR /src/
#10 CACHED

#11 [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app
#11 CACHED

#12 [build 2/7] WORKDIR /src
#12 CACHED

#13 [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "NobetciBorsa_API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
#13 CACHED

#14 [final 1/2] WORKDIR /app
#14 CACHED

#15 [build 3/7] COPY [NobetciBorsa_API.csproj, ./]
#15 CACHED

#16 [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "NobetciBorsa_API.csproj"
#16 CACHED

#17 [final 2/2] COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
#17 CACHED

#18 exporting to image
#18 exporting layers done
#18 writing image sha256:bcbfc63a70dde0c7f61f3c520b4c19cf52ba5a0cb99f7eea40cbde0499a86531 done
#18 naming to docker.io/nobetciborsa/jenkinswithdockerlimitless done
#18 DONE 0.0s
+ docker run -d -p 1001:1001 -p 1000:1000/tcp -p 1000:1000/udp nobetciborsa/jenkinswithdockerlimitless
5379c3bf18f960d8d83499b3c8837112645050521dd91bb56a15781371d8bea0
Finished: SUCCESS
```

it is looking active at port 1001 with "docker ps" command

[image]

I have set the port to 1001 in program.cs

[image]

When I want to access swagger on server ip address this is the error I get. I tried a lot of method but I could not fix that. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't seen your code, but in the ASP.NET Core templates Swagger is only added when you run in `Development` environment, so my assumption would be it's the same for you here.

Here what the template usually looks like:

```cs
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

You are running your container in `Production` environment since you don't explicitly set it otherwise (`Production` is the default), therefore Swagger is not registered with DI and therefore you cannot access it.

You could adjust your `docker run` command to add an option `-e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` which sets the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` which is read by ASP.NET Core and sets the environment to `Development`.

For details please see the [Microsoft Docs - Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0).